# For Couch Surfer, do I have to watch the entirety of the broadcast?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Do I have to watch broadcasts in their entirety or am I able to click the TV screen and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>? Does the screen always show static if I've viewed all broadcasts so far? How many unique broadcasts are there? Are there any special steps required to show a specific broadcast that I should be aware of (e.g. relating to [Media Blitz](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/how-do-i-get-to-the-secret-mission-in-wings-of-liberty))?

> **Couch Surfer**
>   View 10 television news broadcasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the achievement immediately after starting to watch a broadcast, so I'm pretty sure you just have to click on the TV to start 10 separate broadcasts for it to count. You shouldn't need to watch each entire clip.

I can also confirm that there are more then 10 clips in total, since I got the achievement before you go to Char. Just to be sure though, I'd recommend clicking the TV every time you see the floating tooltip text over it, indicating there's a new broadcast.

Comment: I can confirm there is much more than 10 different broadcast since i clicked the TV after each mission and got the achievment way before I was even able to go to Char.

Answer (score 0):

there are definitely more than 10 as I got the achievement even before I finished watching all the broadcasts. Just to be sure, just watch the entire broadcast or keep clicking to "fast forward" to the next dialogue.