# Will picking missions randomly exclude me from doing other missions?

Tags: starcraft-2

As a complete SC2 noob I've started working through the campaign.  When I lost big time on around mission 7 (told you I was a noob!) I started reading the gamesradar strategies.  Having just read about my current mission (Into the Jungle) 11 it looks like I've  skipped 8, 9 and 10.  But 9 mentions having to do this one if you choose to side with the Protoss, which I haven't yet had the option to take.

Will picking missions randomly from the planets available exclude me from doing other missions or will it all just sort itself out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it won't. There are 3 Missions that you won't be able to do as part of your storyline, BUT you can do them after you finish the mission you chose.

Picking missions randomly is okay, you just have to pick according to your style. Case in point: after zero hour, you get to choose between 'unlocking' firebats or marauders. depending on your playing style, you can choose to get firebats first.

Without spoiling too much, the 3 missions don't actually affect you that much. first one doesn't really matter because both unlock the same unit, second one give you a choice over 2 units, and the 3rd is a choice over which enemies you'll face.

All in all, if you just do missions randomly, eventually, you'll end up with only one mission left. That will advance you through the story line(I think if you choose that mission before doing the others, it will warn you about it)

Hope that helps. If you don't care about spoilers, here is an in depth guide for the campaign:

http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign

In addition to all of these, there are some missions that will be easier/harder depending on which units/upgrades/mercs are available to you (e.g. Welcome to the jungle is easier if you have upgraded your missile turrets and stimpacks).

Comment: Thanks for the answer corroded.  At the moment I'm just picking upgrades that sound good.  I've no idea if they match my style of play as I haven't even discovered what that is yet.  Is there a site you can recommend to get an idea of appropriate upgrades/play styles that won't spoil the storyline of the campaign?

Comment: hmm, well it's kinda hard not seeing any spoilers with these guides. the best could offer you was my own experience: i didn't like being spoiled too so what i did was save the game after every mission. that way, i can back track if i chose something wrong(when i feel stuck in getting a map's achievements). the link i gave you also had in depth guides...you can just skip the first paragraph that has the story summary. the guide itself focuses more on what to do and what units to build. basically, just play a map, then if you can't win it, look at the guide for that map.

Comment: Thanks again.  I like to have a go at each mission without reading the guides then look them up if I struggle.  I'll check out those you linked.  I'm glad I headed over here from StackOverflow.  Looks like this site is going to be really useful.

Comment: Yup that's what I actually did. I'm achievement whoring the hard maps right now and I'm still stuck with some missions, since some really take skill, practice and micro to pull off. Just be sure to save after each mission. that way you can easily backtrack your choices. (I for one reloaded the mission before welcome to the jungle, farmed some points for upgrades and redid the mission. easy :) )

Answer (score 4):

The campaign is basically a series of parallel storylines, that ultimately come together and lead into the final story. There is not really a set order to the campaign missions; any numbering on them is just one way to do them.

For example, it sounds like you are doing some of the missions with Tosh. His missions form a series. The "save the colonist" missions also form a series, along with the "find the artifacts" missions. You can progress on each story-arc independently, so you can basically do missions in whichever order you like.

The 3 missions that corroded mentioned in his answer are a different case. In 3 instances, you'll be given a choice of how to do something. Do you help person A, or person B? Each choice actually leads to a different mission. But as corroded also mentioned, you can still play the other mission, through the mission-replay function.

The only mission you need to do something special to unlock is the "secret" mission. You can learn more about that here: [How do I get to the secret mission in Wings of Liberty?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/how-do-i-get-to-the-secret-mission-in-wings-of-liberty) Otherwise, you can play the missions however you like and not miss anything. Which order you play them just determines the order you unlock units, and get money/research points.

Comment: You will still have Spectres. Unit unlocks, mercenary unlocks, armory upgrades, and research unlocks are all "permanent" per campaign play-through. You can, however, go back to a saved game before you aided Tosh, choose to help Nova, and then you will have Ghosts from then on in that play-through.

Comment: @Kyralessa, the only thing you can get from replaying mission choices are the achievements associated with those missions, not the rewards themselves. Also I think you should edit off the names as it may be a spoiler to the original poster

Answer (score 3):

I found [this mission tree](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Wings_of_Liberty_missions) to be helpful *(may contain spoilers, if you consider mission/video titles to be spoilers).*  The three choices correspond to the branches at Outbreak, Welcome to the Jungle, and Card to play.