# Is there a secret mission in Heart of the Swarm?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2 - Wings of Liberty there was one hidden mission ([details here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5434/how-do-i-get-to-the-secret-mission-in-wings-of-liberty)), does Heart of the Swarm also contain a hidden mission, and how do you get to it?

Comment: >! is the spoiler tag; use it!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having completed the campaign and gone through the achievements I will say there is no secret mission in Heart of the Swarm campaign.

The game consists of 20 missions where some of them have an optional order and 7 simple evolution missions that each let you choose 2 directions to evolve a unit.

Comment: I have still much hope that we are missing something... :)

Comment: Running through it once doesn't mean there isn't a secret mission :P

Comment: @Nick122: In Wings of Liberty (why does my brain keep wanting to say Wings of Light???) it did. In order to get the "Wings of Liberty: (difficulty)" achievement you had to complete every mission on that difficulty, *including* the hidden mission. You could even look at what was left to do for the achievement and see that you had done all the missions except "Piercing the Shroud" and promptly think, "Where the heck is 'Piercing the Shroud'?"

Comment: You can do this: unpack all sc2asset files with MPQ extractor utility and browse through them to find out whether there is a map for secret mission or not.

Answer (score -6):

There is a secret mission accessed in the final portion of the Dr. Narud series.  During the mission you will be told to avoid two areas because they are not relevant to helping Kerrigan.  These two areas contain the Tal'Darim bases.  Ignore the warning and find a way to clear both bases while still managing to keep Kerrigan from dying to the null ray.  If you do this you will be told that the swarm has found some of Narud's personal artifacts.  These will lead to a side quest with some fun Easter Eggs and a hint that suggests that

> the identity of Narud is Duran. Narud us Duran backwards same person shapeshifter

Comment: **By ltdowney**: "Can anyone confirm this? Just replayed the mission in question via the Master Archives. Destroyed all buildings in the two base areas and completed the bonus objective to destroy the three Xel'Naga crystals. No additional content was unlocked."

Comment: I wiped every protoss unit off the map, so unless you can't do it from the archives, or you have to do it on brutal, I'm going to disagree.

Comment: I also wiped every building on Normal, No secret mission.

Comment: I did this in a full campaign run and got no such commentary.

Comment: Can we get some screenshots on this to prove it's not an Urban Legend of Zelda?

Comment: Just beat this level on Brutal during my first story-mode run (not from archives). Got all primary- and secondary-objectives, all achievements, and destroyed every protoss unit and building on the map. No secret level. I think we have effectively debunked this as myth.

Comment: The warnings to "avoid two areas" are only to thwart the mastery achievement for that mission. Doesn't seem like there is a secret mission there.

Comment: A creative idea. Samir Duran being Dr. Narud is a pretty crazy / awesome theory.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat It's pretty well spelled out in the game that it's the same being. Not really a theory. It also helps if you've played the [secret mission](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Origin) from Brood War.